# Is there a way to open a Url through the menu of a electron.js app?

Tags: javascript, electron

Im currently building a electron.js application. Now i want that people can open a Url (like:https://stackoverflow.com) in the electron applications menu/navbar. My current code looks like this:

```
   label: 'Menu',
  submenu: [
     {
        label: 'Startseite', click() {
           createWindow()
        }
```

It kinda works it just opens a new windows without closing the old one. Is there any way to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe keep track of the last window created in a global variable, then you can close the window with `oldWindow?.close();`

Keeping track of the old window can be done in the `createWindow` function.